# Cloudfoundry's cf login yields a "connection refused" error message

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am experiencing issues with the latest **bosh-lite** virtual box machine. See [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/Vagrantfile).

I have just downloaded the Vagrantfile and done a

```
vagrant up
```

Then a:

```
cf login -u admin -a 192.168.50.4 -p admin
```

But it give me a:

```
API endpoint: 192.168.50.4
FAILED
connection refused
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3):

Get address of haproxy by logging to it (bosh ssh, then ifconfig). Use address of haproxy as api endpoint.